# Sleep Settings Not Working After Installing Drivers

Tags: drivers, 15.04, suspend, intel-graphics

After installing the latest intel drivers for my computer using the installer from [this](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.0) location, my sleep settings are no longer followed. Sleep settings:

[image]

The computer has been suspending after no activity for 10 minutes when plugged in.

Is there a way to fix this without uninstalling the drivers?
If not, how do I go back to the previously used drivers?

My computer is a Lenovo G50 which dual boots Ubuntu 15.04 with Windows.